# Fetch data from same table using two group by in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have one table name as consultant with 4 fields(id, name,user_type, Created date).I need to write an mysql query for return the count of user_type in each month. ie In my table user type is individual and group(I,G) with 10 entry. 4 are individual and 6 are group. 2 individuals are registered in july and 2 are in august. 4 group members registred in july and 2 in august. So my output is

1) count of individual register in month of july?
2) count of group register in month of july ?
3) count of individual register in month of august ?
4) count of individual register in month of august?

### Sample table Data

## usertable

```
id | Name | user_type | joined_date

-------------------------------------
1  | john  |  I      |      2014-07-16 00:00:00

2  | james |  G      |      2014-07-11 00:00:00

3  | george|  I      |      2014-08-11 00:00:00

4  | aby   |  I      |      2014-07-11 00:00:00

5  | padma |  G      |      2014-08-11 00:00:00

6  | Mick  |  G      |      2014-08-16 00:00:00

7  | Bony  |  G      |      2014-07-21 00:00:00

8  | Sebas |  I      |      2014-08-11 00:00:00

9  | danie |  G      |      2014-07-11 00:00:00

10 | davi  |  G      |      2014-07-01 00:00:00
```

## expected result

```
individual_count  |Group_count| Month              

----------------------------------

  2               | 4         |  July     
  2               | 2         |  August
```

I need to populate This date in a Bar chart. I am bit confuse for this query for last days.Please help me if possible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I see the word "count" often. Use MySQL's aggregate [`COUNT()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/) function, and there's also [`SUM()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/) being another aggregate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(i.id) AS individual_count,
    COUNT(g.id) AS Group_count,
    DATE_FORMAT(u.joined_date, '%M') AS `Month`
FROM usertable AS u
LEFT JOIN usertable AS i ON u.id= i.id AND i.user_type = 'I'
LEFT JOIN usertable AS g ON u.id= g.id AND g.user_type = 'G'

GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(u.joined_date, '%M')
```

That should get you the results you're looking for.

Comment: This is way more inefficient since you are joining 3 tables.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [extract](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) the month from the datetime and group by month and then [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) the individuals and groups on their own.